# QML reports ReferenceError: XYZ is not defined on C++ object added to context

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml, referenceerror

I've started learning `QML` recently (after trying it out a long time ago) and I'm stuck at the way `Qt` `C++` code interacts with `QML` and vice versa.

I have a `Counter` which has the following header:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int count
           READ getCount
           WRITE setCount
           NOTIFY signalCountChanged)
public:
    Counter(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    int getCount();
    void setCount(int count);
signals:
    void signalCountChanged(int);
public slots:
    void slotStart();
private slots:
    void slotTimeout();
private:
    int count;
    QTimer *timer;
};
```

My `main.cpp` is as follows:

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml/QQmlContext>
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickItem>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include "counter.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Counter>("org.qmlplayground.counter", 0, 1, "Counter");

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QObject *viewO = dynamic_cast<QObject*>(view.rootObject());
    Counter c;
    // Register Counter instance as "counter" property of top level context so that it can be accessed from within the QML code (for example: set the value count)
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("counter", &c);

    QObject::connect(viewO, SIGNAL(signalStartCounter()),
            &c, SLOT(slotStart()));
    QObject::connect(viewO, SIGNAL(signalQuit()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

and finally part of my `QML` (the `main.qml` which is loaded in the `QQuickView` while the rest being an UI form):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

// Importing some JavaScript files
import "qrc:/loggingFunctions.js" as LOG
import "qrc:/parseFunctions.js" as PARSE

// Importing a Qt C++ custom module
import org.qmlplayground.counter 0.1

MainForm {
    property int countState: counter.count // ERROR HERE
    signal signalStartCounter()
    signal signalQuit()

    anchors.fill: parent

    textInputMouseArea.onClicked: {
        LOG.logger("Clicked! Selecting all text in text input field", "N")
        textInput.selectAll()
    }

    textInput.onAccepted: {
        if(textInput.text === "quit") signalQuit()//Qt.quit();
        if(textInput.text === "help") textInput.text = LOG.logger("Displaying help", "H");

        var res = PARSE.parseInput(textInput.text);
        if(res && (typeof res === 'object') && res.constructor === Array) {
            switch(res[0]) {
            case "fact":
                labelOutput.text = res[1];
                break;
            case "count":
                counter.count = res[1];
                signalStartCounter();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    onCountStateChanged:
        console.log("Hello")

    textInput.onTextChanged:
        console.log("Text changed");
}
```

As you can see I've already tested two signals sent from my `QML` to my `C++` code one being connected to my `QGuiApplication`'s slot `quit()` and the other being connected to my `counter`'s slot `slotStart()`. It works fine. It seems that the line

```
counter.count = res[1];
```

doesn't cause any issues (perhaps because it's `JS` and not `QML`?). Now I want to read the `count` value of my `Counter` instance and update my UI accordingly. If I'm not mistaken every `QML` property automatically gets a couple of things one of these being the `onChanged` method (event handler or whatever it's called).

When I run my code however I get

```
`qrc:/main.qml:21: ReferenceError: counter is not defined
```

I thought that doing `view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("counter", &c);` would be enough but it seems that I'm missing something. So the more general question would be how do I **properly** make a `C++` object visible in `QML` context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This took me perhaps 2 hours to figure out (I posted my question when I was on the verge of commiting a suicide :D) but the answer was really obvious: how can I call for a property which hasn't been initialized yet? The solution to my problem is basically to move the `setContextProperty()` **BEFORE** I load the `QML` file:

```
// ...
QQuickView view;
Counter c;
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("counter", &c);
view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
// ...
```

By doing so the property is first added to the root context of the `view` and after that the additional `QML` stuff is loaded but the `counter` property is still present). With the previous version of my code I was basically trying to access `counter` inside my `QML` file **BEFORE** I have added it as a property.

Comment: I consider `setContextProperty` evil and prefer to create objects in the QML code.

Comment: I wanted to do that too but from what I understand you cannot use slots and signals between QML and C++ code without instantiating the C++ parts and registering them in the QML context. If you know how to do that please do tell. I ended up with this because I was unable to find any other way.

Comment: To instantiate your C++ class in QML, write `Counter { id: counter; }`. Then there is no need for the `setContextProperty`.

Comment: I know how to do that. What I don't know is how to connect the C++ slots and signals. :P

Comment: Call `counter.slotStart()` instead of `signalStartCounter()`?

Comment: Ah, thanks. And how do you bind a `signal blah()` (defined in QML) to `slotBlah()`?

Comment: Yes, that's not obvious: `onBlah: counter.slotBlah();`. Actually, I rarely have to define things like `signal blah()` in QML, because for the most of the tasks the `property` is convenient enough.