# Change QML Listview delegate from C++

Tags: c++, listview, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to change the delegate of qml listview from C++ but currently I stuck at how to change the alias which represents the delegate property.

**Update on details:**
*I have multiple delegates in separated qml files, in my application there are many screens, each screen will have different UI of listview, what I want is something like:*

*Pass delegate file name to C++ function >>> C++ function set delegate property of listView (or thing like that) >>> listview loads corresponding delegate.*

My qml file looks like:

```
Item {
    id: root
    property alias listViewDelegate: listView.delegate

    ListView{
        id: listView
        delegate: MyDelegate{} // I have MyDelegate.qml file, it's working well
        model: listModel
    }

    // List model
    MyListModel {
        id: listModel
    }
}
```

I tried to change listViewDelegate alias from C++ using setProperty() method but got no luck (error in fact).

```
qmlObj->setProperty("listViewDelegate", componentDelegate);
```

How to achieve this? Or anyone can suggest me the better method to achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank everyone, I just figured out a way to do that by using javascript, seems complicated but it works.

I add this javascript function into my root Item

```
function loadListViewDelegate(file){
    var component = Qt.createComponent(file);
    if(component && (component.status === Component.Ready))
    {
        listView.delegate = component;
        return file;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Then I invoke this function from C++, with parameter is the delegate qml file. It looks like this:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qmlObj, "loadListViewDelegate", Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue), Q_ARG(QVariant, "delegate_screen_home.qml"));
```

[How to invoke qml javascript method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html)

Answer (score 4):

I think that there is a better way to do this.

Steps:

1) create a model in c++ side.

```
class Model : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(qint32 status READ status WRITE setStatus NOTIFY statusChanged)
public:
  Model(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
  ...
}
```

2) pass the Model Object to qml by setContextProperty

```
Model model;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("model1", &model);
```

3) binding your delegate of ListView on Model.status

```
ListView {
    id: listview
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 20
    model: listmodel
    delegate: model1.status === 0 ? delegate1 : delegate2
}
```

4) now you can change delegate by setStaus() in c++ side.

```
model.setStatus(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the matter is I have multiple delegates in separated qml files, in my application there are many screens, each screen will have different UI of listview, what I want is something like:
Pass delegate file name to C++ function >>> C++ function set delegate property of listView (or thing like that) >>> listview loads corresponding delegate.

Comment: remember: always [call `setContextProperty` **BEFORE** `setSource`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38500324/3427520), otherwise you will get an error *listmodel is not defined*

Answer (score 2):

The property listViewDelegate has to be assigned to the ListView, so that when you modify the ListViewDelegate property, the ListView will be notified of this and update the delegate.

```
Item {
    id: root
    property Component listViewDelegate: myDelegate

    MyDelegate { 
          id:  myDelegate
    }

    ListView{
        id: listView
        delegate: listViewDelegate
        model: listModel
    }

    // List model
    MyListModel {
        id: listModel
    }
}
```